# Dynamic selects not separating options

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, select, lightbox

So I have a dynamic option on a form within a Lightbox,so when you select either UK or US is gives you two (or should) give you either a list of the UK counties or the US states. The problem being that my options seemed to have merged?

So I need the two lists to be separated so when you click Us you only get the states and when UK is clicked you get the UK counties?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uEEyT/1/)

```
$(document).on("change", "select.common", function() { 
    $("select.common").not(this).val( this.value ) //added .not(this) since we dont need to change the value of the select being interacted with
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to filter city option to show either 'UK' or 'US' based on the selected country. Here is an example that I just created to show the basic filter:

```
// Set default values
var ukCities = ['Avon', 'Bedfordshire', 'Berkshire'];
var usCities = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona'];

$(document).on("change", "select.country", function() {
    // Get the current country value
    var country = $("select.country").val();
    var cities;
    if(country === 'UK'){
        cities = ukCities;
    }
    else{
        cities = usCities;
    }
    // Clear options
    $("select.city").empty();
    // Add new options
    $.each(cities, function(index, element){
            $("select.city").append($("<option></option>").attr("value", country).text(element));
    });
});
// Default data is set as UK
$("select.country").val('UK').trigger('change');
```

See on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uEEyT/2/).

Comment: So that works as I would expect it too. Now the only issue I have is that when I place this in a lightbox it fails?

Comment: How did you place it in the lightbox? What was the error you got?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this.  Below it is achieved by using jQuery to hide/show the options that fit.  FYI - I changed the value of each state to a class, because you'll probably need the value to return the actual state when the form is submitted later.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.country').on('change', function () {
        var country = $(this).val();
        $('.common option').each(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass(country)) {
                $(this).show();
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Pretty sure this won't work in all browsers (hiding select options)

Comment: do you have a demo of this sorry? This also is causing me an issue when sat in a lightbox it fails to load?

Comment: Apologies - here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uEEyT/1/).  Also, @KevinB might be right - I only tested this in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the previous content doing something like:

```
$('#element').value('');
```

And then do your thing...

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate on this at all I am not sure I understand?